# Unable to built docker error when copy zip file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to built docker, but keep throwing error 
`ERROR: Service 'telegraf' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder163419820/telegraf-telemetry.zip: no such file or directory`
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk add curl git make unzip
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN pwd
RUN ls /tmp/
COPY telegraf.zip /tmp/
RUN unzip /tmp/telegraf.zip
RUN ls -la /tmp/
```

I would like to copy zip to /tmp/ and unzip and copy to `go` folder

Comment: I'm a little confused: your error message means `telegraf-telemetry.zip`, but your `Dockerfile` only has `telegraf.zip`.

Comment: That zip file is on your host system, in the same directory as the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i extract the file and use COPY the content into the directory. 
Thanks